# Injecting different Javascript based on the current page being viewed in WebView React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Background**

I built an IOS application that uses WebView to load a website and navigate a user through 4 pages by clicking the buttons with Javascript. I am converting this application to React Native now and when the second page loads the Javascript does not seem to fire off. I am assuming this is because it is lost but I am not sure if React Native continues to inject the javascript on each page load or only on the first page that loads which could be lost after the client reloads or changes.

**Example**

```
const injectedJavaScript: = `
    let currentStep = "login";
    if(currentStep === 'login') {
      document.getElementById('userID').value =  '${
        this.props.username
      }'; document.getElementById('userPassword').value = '${
        this.props.password
      }'; document.getElementById('login').click();
      currentStep = 'agreeToTerms';
    } else if(currentStep === 'agreeToTerms' && window.location.href === "https://www.example.com") {
      currentStep = 'download';
      document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click();
    }
    `;


  <WebView
        ignoreSslError={true}
        source={{ uri: "https://www.example.com" }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 400, width: 400 }}
        injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
        onError={() => this.webviewError(e)}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
      />
```

**Question**

Please tell me the correct way to inject specific Javascript to the WebView depending on which page is currently being viewed in the WebView?

In my example above I am showing 2 steps. Step 1 is successful but when the WebView loads the second page the second step of Javascript is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

change your inject script to

```
 <WebView
    ignoreSslError={true}
    source={{ uri: "https://www.example.com" }}
    style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 400, width: 400 }}
    injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    onError={() => this.webviewError(e)}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    onLoad={this.updateInjectedJavaScript}
  />
```

so that it will be executed when ever your page is reloaded.

Comment: This still has the same problem. I am pretty sure the injected JS is gone once the second page is rendered. Are you sure that it should still be there?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I figured it out. If you simply use, `onLoad={this.updateInjectedJavaScript}` every time a new page loads that function will fire and I can inject new JS into the WebView by keeping track of which page I have directed my user to. `this.webview.injectJavaScript(injectedJavaScript);` if you would like to update your solution for other people I would be happy to accept it. thanks again!